# How does unix timestamp deal with leapseconds?

Tags: unix-timestamp

[Leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) are added to correct for variations in the Earth's rotation. However, unlike leap years these do not occur at regular intervals (because it is not due to a systematic error, like leap years).

How are leap seconds handled by systems that use unix timestamps? Are leap seconds hard-coded into updates of programming languages that implement timestamps?

**Update**: [looks like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Non-synchronous_Network_Time_Protocol-based_variant) Unix timestamps don't deal with leap seconds

Answer (score 1):

It is handled in the time server, not in the programming languages per se.  If a second is being lost, the time server reports a 61st second at the end of the day (with a value of 60); if gained, the seconds of UTC go 56, 57, 58, 00, 01.